# pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function past_match_sim at 0x7fa26e03b7b8>: attribute lookup past_match_sim on __main__ failed

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I am trying to run multiple files at a single time using multiprocessing module.....

```
import multiprocessing
import schedule
import time
if len(abc)==1:
    def live_run1():     
        def lv1():
            exec(open('/path to file/file1.py').read())                            
        def lv_s():
            exec(open('/path to file/file2.py').read())
        import multiprocessing
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            p11 = multiprocessing.Process(target=lv1)
            p12 = multiprocessing.Process(target=lv_s)
            p11.start()
            p12.start()
            p11.join()
            p12.join()                        
            time.sleep(500)
            exec(open('/path to file/file3.py').read())
            return schedule.CancelJob
        schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(live_run1)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

the error i got :

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function past_match_sim at 0x7fa26e03b7b8>: attribute lookup past_match_sim on __main__ failed
```

I am not able to come out from this problem....

Appreciate any help

Comment: Move functions `lv1` and  'lv_s` to global scope, that is, do not nest them within `live_run1`.  What is `exec`? Is this supposed to be the Python built-in function or something else that has not be declared in your post (you should be posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which this does not appear to be and tagging your question with the platform on which you are running, such as `windows` or `linux` whenever you tag a question with `multiprocessing`)?

Comment: sorry for the lacking informations.....i am running this code in linux(this is file i am trying to schedule using cronjob).Also exec() is a function to run a python script file(inbuilt)....l tried the functions in global scope but  still I getting the same error...

Comment: The built-in function takes a **string** argument that is Python code, for example `exec('x = 7 + 3')` or a  **code object** argument created with the `compile`  function. You are passing neither. Why are you using `exec` at all? Why isn't the definition of function `lv1` just `open('/path to file/file1.py').read()`? Of course, I don't know what the purpose of just reading a file and then doing nothing the results is. But that's another matter.

Answer (score 1):

Possible fixups to your code can be following.

I modified code not to use `schedule` module because it has some troubles pickling even global functions, hence I decided to implement same functionality without `schedule`:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow70032763#main.py)

```py
import multiprocessing, time, datetime

def lv1():
    exec(open('0603.py').read())
    
def lv_s():
    exec(open('0604.py').read())

def live_run1():
    p11 = multiprocessing.Process(target=lv1)
    p12 = multiprocessing.Process(target=lv_s)
    p11.start()
    p12.start()
    p11.join()
    p12.join()                        
    time.sleep(2)
    exec(open('0605.py').read())

def today_at(hour, minute = 0, second = 0):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return datetime.datetime(
        year = now.year, month = now.month,
        day = now.day, hour = hour,
        minute = minute, second = second)

def now():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

def run_at(hour, minute, second = 0, *, done = set()):
    at = today_at(hour, minute, second)
    if str(at) not in done and now() >= at and (
        now() - at <= datetime.timedelta(seconds = 10)
    ):
        print('started running at', now())
        live_run1()
        print('finished running at', now())
        done.add(str(at))
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('now is', now())
    while True:
        run_at(7, 3, 40)
        run_at(10, 40)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
now is 2021-11-22 07:03:32.389326
started running at 2021-11-22 07:03:40.404687
0603
0604
0605
finished running at 2021-11-22 07:03:42.447017
```

Comment: still it having the above mentioned error while execution....................

Comment: @Ashin Just fixed my code, please put again look at my answer. This pickling error happens due to `schedule` module, it doesn't support `multiprocessing` run, hence I decided to implement identical functionality without `schedule`. See my code, it does exactly what you want but without `schedule`. See very end of my code to see how to use my code, there is `run_at(...)` to run at specified time instead of using schedule.

Comment: I tried still same error.....But I am really thankful to you for taking that much effort in solving this error.Nice job @Arty

Comment: @Ashin Did you try my current code from my answer? Did you notice that I changed my code already to different one? You can't have exactly same error, because you have `schedule`-package error, and I don't use `schedule` anymore at all! Can you please post exact error text that you get right now when you run my code (from my answer) on your computer, without doing any modifications to my code? Click `Try it online!` link from my answer, it runs my code Online and show no error, by this link [I get this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd8AD.png), which shows no error in the console on right.

Comment: @Arty....I am really sorry for the delayed reply....I tried your code again and return the same error which i mentioned....bt your code is error free and running at another scenerio...so i think the actual problem is another not due to the schedule module....Also one thing,the file1.py is also doing someother multiprocessing(pool) inside it so i think the error becuase of that.

Comment: @Ashin Yes, my code has no errors, just try to run only my code, only single my script without any modifications, and you'll see that there are no errors. You may also click `Try it online!` link at the top of my code and see that there is no error when you run my code without modifications. I'm sure that error is in some other place of your scripts that you incorporate my code into. Please share your whole code that throws error, I'll quickly find out for you the real reason of error. You may share code through either github.com/pastebin.com/hastebin.com websites. Or add code to your question